# Creating arcs and set color to them with quartz

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, quartz-graphics

I want to create a circle with a border color. Im not familiar with quartz but I know that this is how an arc is created:

```
    CGContextAddArc(<#CGContextRef c#>, <#CGFloat x#>, <#CGFloat y#>, <#CGFloat radius#>, <#CGFloat startAngle#>, <#CGFloat endAngle#>, <#int clockwise#>)
```

But I dont really know what the "#CGContextRef c" means. And can anybody tell how to add style to it, i.e color, border etc.

This code doesnt work. Whats wrong?

```
- (void)circle
{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 225, 0);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0, 255, 0);
CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you drawing into a UIView or a Core Animation Layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CGContext is hidden away by UIKit, which supplies higher-level means of working with graphics, such as [`UIBezierPath`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html), but in some cases you'll have to drop down to using the Quartz API directly.

You can get the `CGContextRef` by calling [`UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW11), like so-

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

Once you're here you can use the whole library of [CGContext functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html), such as [`CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor) and [`CGContextSetLineWidth`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextSetLineWidth) to draw the arc the way you like.

Note that if you use the function you mentioned, after adding the arc to the CGContext's path, you'll still have to 'stroke' it using `CGContextDrawPath`. If you just want to draw a circle, you might be better off with `CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect`.

Comment: Thanks! But how to I tell the "CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor" to set the specific shape?

Comment: The setting applies to any drawing made after the color is set. I think that's what you're asking!

Comment: - (void)circle
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 225, 0);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0, 255, 0);
    CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
}
This doesn't seems to work. Whats wrong?

Comment: Firstly, setting the color with an alpha value of 0 makes it totally transparent. So use alpha=1. Secondly, `CGRectMake` just makes a CGRect structure, it's doing nothing here. Use `CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect` instead of `CGRectMake` (but you may have to use CGRectMake as an argument to `CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect`)

Comment: Note: CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor() takes floats in the rage 0.0–1.0 for the color channels. Values above and below are clipped. You should use 1.0, not 255. See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor).